# Improving queries that use view

Tags: sql-server

Is there an effective approache beside using INNER JOIN or index to optimize queries that use VIEW

```
CREATE VIEW tableView AS 
SELECT A1, A2, B1 as Price, C1 as ItemNumber
FROM A, B, C 
WHERE A.A1 = B.B1
AND A.A2 = C.C1;
```

Example of query

```
 SELECT * FROM TableView WHERE Price = ‘100’ AND ItemNumber = 'R34';
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use those options? I voted to close because the question is arbitrary. It helps no future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effective approaches are using appropriate indexes on the underlying tables and general tuning of SQL Server.

There is nothing specific to views that can be optimized (except for the same general issues with regular queries - not using functions that cause table reads/index scans versus index seeks etc...).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid table indexes because the data exists in two different tables then you could create a `schema bound view` which allows you to create a `composite index` on both columns in the `sql where` clause (Price,ItemNumber).